# How do I create an explicit app ID using Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

So far I've been able to create an iOS Team Provisioning profile with `Xcode`, but it looks like it is only possible to create it using a Wildcard App Id.

Since I need to enable Push Notifications it must be an explicit app Id. I know it is very easy to create using the member center, but my question is:

How do I create it using only `XCode`?

Comment: Why can't you use the Member Center to create an ID?

Comment: I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle and it only seems to find iOS Team Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. How does using Delphi prevent you from using the Dev Member Center?

Answer (score 4):

You must create an explicit App ID in the Developer Member Center. There is no other option of where to create this.